# How to Connect Azure Worker/Web role to Azure Iaas VMs without using public IP's?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-virtual-machine

We want to run MongoDB and some custom services on Azure Iaas VMs and connect to them with our roles but we do not want to have public IP exposure on the VMs.

If possible what is the best way of doing this?

If not possible is this on the roadmap?

We can add the VM's under the same cloud service and they can communicate happily, the roles are in same deployment so they communicate, but issue between the vm's and roles. We appreciate that the Iaas stuff is still in preview.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your Windows Azure Web/Worker Role and Windows Azure Virtual Machine in the same DC you can access them directly using internal IP address using Virtual Networking (Vnet) using internal Endpoints. To achieve it first you would need to create a Virtual Network and then add your Virtual Machine to this VNet. VNet will give your internal IP address and your Web/Worker Role can communicate to this internal IP address.

You can not do mix mode deployment directly from Windows Azure Preview Portal (it is not supported in preview yet) however you can use PowerShell VNet cmdlets to get it configured and working. To need further assistance with VNet team you can contact them directly [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork/threads).